# Custom Font doesn't work after WordPress Migration

Tags: css, wordpress

I have just migrated my website from https://www.dpowercool.com/demo/ to https://www.trendybuz.com/
with Duplicator plugin but the custom font 'Kanit' doesn't work.
I have already checked via backend and see that Kanit font is set up.

and here is CSS code

```
body:not(.block-editor-page):not(.wp-core-ui), body:not(.block-editor-page):not(.wp-core-ui) pre {
font-family: Kanit;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 24px;
text-transform: none;
color: #000000;}
```

Thank You

Comment: You have cross origin issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have cross origin issue in site.

Just place below code in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer. However, I can't up-vote the answer due to my reputation.